# Why do Gmail attachments I send in order appear out of order in my sent mail, and does the recipient receive them in order?

Tags: gmail-attachments

After clicking attachments, I selected files in the order I wanted them to appear to the recipient. All photos were in numerical order. Before sending the email, I confirmed that they were in order at the bottom of the page. Then I clicked send. If I were to save my message as a draft or if I check my sent mail, they will appear out of order. Uploading them one by one might have a different effect-I haven't tried it-but hopefully Google has addressed this issue since a user posted a similar problem in 2016 because this is a very inconvenient way to send a large number of attachments.